# Angular 2 website reflects real-time changes on different computers

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, localhost

This might be a novice question but i am creating a website on Angular 2. NPM defaults the server to `http://localhost:3000`. I tried to open the website from another computer by calling my ip address `http://10.x.x.x:3000` and the website works fine.

But when i am typing in an input field from Computer 1, it is reflecting real-time changes in the Computer 2's browser. The problem exists for input texts, showing/hiding divs and even for input radios. The problem also exists if two browser from the same computer are running in parallel.

I understand that the problem might be because of the same port but don't know the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are likely using browsersync in some of your build scripts. That will keep browsers everywhere in sync.

To test multiple clients, you need the non-browsersync build (whatever your project calls that).